# docker _tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display

Tags: python, docker

ubuntu 16.04 ,
nvidia-docker installed,
a tensorflow container running,
python 2.7

i want to run a simple python code inside the container. shown as below

```
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()

canvas_width = 80
canvas_height = 40
w = Canvas(master, 
           width=canvas_width,
           height=canvas_height)
w.pack()

y = int(canvas_height / 2)
w.create_line(0, y, canvas_width, y, fill="#476042")


mainloop()
```

but when i run this, this error comes

> _tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable

and according to this site https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8838 
i committed my container to an image, and run it again with the -e flag:

> -e DISPLAY=:0.0

but here comes the error:

> _tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display :0.0

i'm not using ssh to login the container.
could anyone can give me advice about it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is because the container couldn't access the x11 socket of the host. so when doing the docker run, need to include these two flag.

```
-v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix
-e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY
```

and after this, we need to do another operation. because the default settings of X11 only allows local users to print. so we need to change this to all users.

```
$ sudo apt-get install x11-xserver-utils
$ xhost +
```

then the problem solved.

Comment: It works on Ubuntu! How to make this work on Windows ?

Comment: Im following this and I still get "couldn't connect to display "127.0.0.1:0.0""

Comment: Is `xhost +` really safe since this allows ALL users to connect? Shouldn't this be `xhost +local:docker` instead (if using docker in local)?

Answer (score 6):

> _tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display "localhost:0.0"

i have same error message, solved. (at least the error message gone!)

```
export MPLBACKEND='Agg'
```