# Replit: Getting error 'couldn't connect to display' on a repl using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, replit

Getting the following error on a `repl` of mine ([Tic-Tac-Toe GUI](https://replit.com/@BileshGanguly/Tic-Tac-Toe-GUI)) where I'm using `Tkinter`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 99, in <module>
    root = tk.Tk()
  File "/nix/store/hd4cc9rh83j291r5539hkf6qd8lgiikb-python3-3.10.8/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2299, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display ":0"
```

It was working up until yesterday.

This seems to be an error faced by people working on less popular Linux distros ([local machine _tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display ":0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59006466/local-machine-tkinter-tclerror-couldnt-connect-to-display-0)) and the following update to the PATH variable seems to be fixing the issue.

```
export DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY
```

Not sure why suddenly this became an issue, also, not sure how I can fix it on Replit. Any suggestions/help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why not ask them?. Anyway I don't think this will be reproducible, because the DISPLAY value "unix:0" is equivalent to ":0".